# How to make a global variable from fetch data on a database (Store and retrieving it) using javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

Good day, after reading so many forums and QnA's. It's still unclear to me how can I store data globally and retrieve it whenever I need them and/or retrieve them on the other FXML forms.

Here is what I just started. First, I made a public java class for storing and retrieving my data.

**TestPassData.java**

```
public class TestPassData {

    private static int PassData;

    public static int getPassData() {
        return PassData;
    }

    public static void setPassData(int PassData) {
        TestPassData.PassData = PassData;
    }

}
```

then a controller where I fetch the data from the database and store it to the TestPassData

**FetchDataController.java**

```
con = pst.prepareStatement("SELECT Emp_ID FROM Employee WHERE UserName = ? AND Password = ?");
pst.setString(1, un);
pst.setString(2, pw);
rs = pst.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()){
      TestPassData.setPassData(rs.getInt("Emp_ID");
}
```

Then here's where my problem is. I can't retrieve the data I stored on the variable.

**RetrieveStoredDataController.java**

```
lblPassID.setText(Integer.toString(TestPassData.getPassData()));
```

I always get 0, as a return value. Hope someone will share their idea on this.

Comment: You should really rethink your entire design here, as using a global class to pass information between other classes is a horrible idea.

Comment: Also, please learn the Java naming conventions and stick to them (ie: variable names should be camelCase with the first letter being lowercase).  I suggest going back to a few introductory Java tutorials to get a better grasp on the basics. That isn't meant to sound harsh, but will **truly** help you in the long run, before you develop too many bad habits. :)

Comment: thanks, I will sir :), but why is it bad to store data from a global variable, I mean, I think it is way easier for me to call just call it to the other controllers

Comment: Primarily because it exposes that data to your entire application, even to classes that have nothing to do with that data. This violates several principles of programming in general. Also, what happens when you build a very large application, with a whole lot of data? Now you have a massive class full of public data that would be a nightmare to maintain. So no, not easier. :P

Comment: I'm sure there are other, more important, reasons that smarter programming veterans can add to this. But those two reasons are the first to jump out at me.

Comment: Thank you so much for the heads up :) So regarding my problem above, how can I possibly call the Employee ID from other FXML forms? I'm using multiple scenes just to make the system work smoothly in the future, but it is hard for me to get that unique data (Employee ID). I mean, it is like when a user logins, he can do whatever he wants from all data belonging only to him.

Comment: You could create a `User` object that includes access information. Then just pass that `User` two each controller that needs it...

Comment: Some dependency injection framework may be a good idea, though I don't know, if you want to tackle advanced topics yet. In this case you're missing a [mcve] though. You may identify the issue yourself though, if you use e.g. a debugger with breakpoints in the methods accessing the data. The fact that you're getting 0 indicates that the loop body was not run before retrieving the data, either because it runs later, or because the query does not return results. (In cases where you expect a single row to be returned I recommend using `if (rs.next()) { ... } else {...}`, since allows for checks...

Answer (score 0):

Michael Castillo what Zephyr stated about using Global Variable is very true. My view is with great power comes greater responsibility. We set a static variable in our Database Helper Class because we want something to only happen once in another Controller Class

```
static String firstTIME = "TRUE";
```

What you need to be concerned with is that firstTIME is now always "TRUE" so you need to manage it or it will manage you. Set it to " " or "FALSE" In the new Controller Class that you want to use this powerful global variable be sure it is imported like this

```
import static checkbook.CreateTableUtil.firstTIME;
```

Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: Thank you, sir,  I finally made a global variable passing a `private static variable` to a public interface.

I tried studying Spring, but it's more advanced than I thought it would be. Still in the future, I'm planning on adding Dependency Injection using Spring Framework on the system I was building. I guess this should do the trick. Thank you for your insights. I learn a lot. Specially, naming conventions in java